# Apple Developer DNS Broken

Tags: dns, accounts

I'm trying to create a developer account at developer.apple.com, but every time I click "Register", it says the server at developercms.apple.com couldn't be found. Is this happening to anyone else? How can I get past this?

Comment: This might be a transient Internet access problem. I experienced one just this minute toward `https://developer.apple.com`. One minute later I reached it within 2 s. I can't test it since this server is blocking `ping`.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have been a transient issue on Apple's end which has now been resolved.